# Remove top and bottom border of UISearchBar and shadow?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a .xib with a UISearchBar.

I am looking to remove the top and bottom borders as seen in this image: [image]

There is also what looks like a shadow underneath the top border.

I have tried changing backgrounds/tint colours etc, but struggling to get it to disappear.

Any help would be welcome, any ideas?

EDIT

So the code below allows me to get rid of the border at the top and bottom, but not the weird drop shadow. I've added green background to show it more clearly.

[image: See]

Also, what would be the best way to add a border around the text box (rather than the view)?? Thanks

//** This is what I'm trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107058/uiviewcontroller-sizing-as-maincontroller-within-uisplitviewcontroller

and here is the code I am using.

```
import UIKit

class TopSearchViewController: UIView {

    var expanded: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBAction func advancedSearchButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if expanded == 0 {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
                self.trailingConstraint.constant = 200
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
            expanded = 1
        } else {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
                self.trailingConstraint.constant = 25
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
            expanded = 0
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TopSearchViewController", owner: self, options: nil)

        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth

        self.addSubview(contentView)

        self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        println(searchBar)

        for subview in searchBar.subviews {
            println("hello")

            var textField : UITextField

            if (subview.isKindOfClass(UITextField)) {
                textField = subview as! UITextField
                textField.borderStyle = .None
                textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
                textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
                textField.layer.cornerRadius = 14
                textField.background = nil;
                textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
        }

    }

    func viewDidLoad() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 91):

Set the bar's `backgroundImage` to an *empty* `UIImage`, **not** `nil`:

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

You may also set the `barTintColor`, as you specified in your comment below.

Comment: Superb :) Good idea :) tq

Comment: This did not work for me, as the barTintColor does not take after setting the backgroundImage to an empty UIImage

Comment: @GregHilston, but that's not what OP's question was. If you're trying to have a slightly translucent, colored bar, then you need to set the `backgroundImage` to a non-empty `UIImage` that you've created programmatically and set to be the desired color. (You can't set an image's color in Interface Builder.)

Comment: @NRitHOh man, I totally misread OP's question. Thank you for the followup comment!

Comment: This still applies in iOS 13, and seems to be the only thing I can find that works reliably. The other approach of overlapping views by 1px is much more likely to break with layout changes or changes in the size of these elements with iOS version changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

With Xcode 11, in the Storyboard, you can set 'Search Style' to 'Minimal.'

In code: `searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal`

Comment: Helped remove the top and bottom borders. Thanks !

Comment: This removed a border for me that appeared between the search bar and the Selected Scope button accessory view, which the other approach listed in he answers here did not hide when the view was displayed with larger accessibility type sizes. So thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I have tried all answers, but they didn't remove the 1px inner shadow of UISearchBar's UITextfield inside.

I solved this problem by increasing white border's width.
It overlaps on shadow.

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 10
searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Answer (score 7):

**# Method 1**

With Thanking to @andrewlundy, Storyboard method is like this. (Xcode 11.*)

1. Select UISearch at the storyboard (assumed: you have already dragged an UISearch Bar to your UIView/UIViewController)
2. Goto `Attribute Inspector` and you will see `Search Style`
3. Select `Minimal` from `Search Style` dropdown.

[image]
[image]

That's it...

**# Method 2**

Else **if you want to do this programmatically**, in swift

1. create an `IBOutlet` for UISearch in your ViewController swift file
2. `searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal`

here instead of `searchBar`, put `your UISearch outlet's name`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

**EDIT:**

I believe that shadow is caused by inner `UITextField`. Try with below code:

```
var textField : UITextField

for subview in searchBar.subviews {
    if (subview.isKindOfClass(UITextField)) {
        textField = subview as! UITextField
        textField.borderStyle = .None
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        textField.background = nil;
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: So I did try that within viewDidLoad, but after putting it elsewhere, it now works. 

However, that only gets rid of the line above and below, and not of the weird tint colour. (I know that it's related to tint because it disappears if I change it to white)

Comment: Please take a look at my edited post. I think I answered your original question and this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. Please see my updated code.

Answer (score 2):

There's another trick:

For the bottom border, you can cover it by bellow view( for example: tableView) by -1 pixel.

For the top border, move it up 1 pixel to under navigation bar also fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code in swift5 to implement searchbar

1. List item

---

```
    let searchbar:  UISearchBar =
     {
    let sear = UISearchBar()
    sear.tintColor = Mycolor().lightgray1
    sear.backgroundColor = Mycolor().lightgray1
    sear.barTintColor =  Mycolor().lightgray1
    sear.placeholder = "Search Asset"
    sear.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    sear.barStyle = .default
    sear.backgroundImage = UIImage()
   // sear.addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10), color: UIColor.darkGray, radius: 20, opacity: 5)

    return sear

}()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(searchbar)
}


override func viewLayoutMarginsDidChange() {
    self.searchbar.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

guard let searchTextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField else { return }
        searchTextField.borderStyle = .none

if you want to remove the border completely
Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

Try `searchTextField` property for minimum deployment target iOS 13 in case other suggested options not working for you.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
        }
```