# Searchbar without lines ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar above a UITableview in swift
This search bar looks like this

[image]

How can I remove the gray lines?

thanks!

Comment: You image is not clear can you tell me which grey line and please show some code what you had try out first

Comment: Don't you see gray lines behind the search bar?

Comment: Top gray lines above the search text???

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33151798/5381663 ?

Comment: No, the gray lines behind the bar box

Comment: clear the background color of UIsearch bar

Comment: This guy has a acceptance level of 0

Answer (score 0):

Set your searchbar bartint color to white[image]

Comment: I did, but the problem persist

Comment: check your Translucent checkmark also make sure your scopeBar  and Background field are empty in the identity inspector

Answer (score 0):

Its not answerable without knowing the configuration if this view. The lines come either from a superview or the view itself. The lines look like an old UIColor that was commonly used up to iOS 6. 
Are you using an older NIB or Storyboard from a previous project?

Either way, check the barTintColor. It is either defined in the Storyboard/NIB file or set using code (on the object or as appearance).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problem but restarting XCode I solved it.