# How to change the bar tint color of search bar and table view's color when search bar is active and disabled?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFISO.png)

How do I change the color of the background (not search bar textfield)

Also how do I increase the gap between status bar and search bar? It looks too close.

I have tried this but doesn't work as expected:

```
 func configureSearchController ()
    {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0;

        //searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey()



        for subView in searchController.searchBar.subviews {
            for subViewOne in subView.subviews {
                if subViewOne is UITextField {
                    subViewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.searchBarTextFieldGrey()
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey()

    }
```

Comment: You need to set the tableView controller as the delegate of the search bar in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Try something like this: `self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self`. Put this line of code to `viewDidLoas()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate of the search bar in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: thank you, but how do I have different colors bar tint when search bar comes active/inactive.

Comment: @AnnoThra Depending on what you need, you can set the bar tint colour when the delegate methods are called. Simply set the `barTintColor` property. I will have a look at these when I’m back at my computer and update my answer.

Comment: @AnnoThra Actually, the code you have should change the tint color as long as you set the delegate correctly.

Comment: No but the gap is still there. Check screenshot

Comment: Is it that dark line between search bar and the tableview?

Comment: Changing that can be a little tricky - check some of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33146848/8289095) question.